# Unexpected token '?' no stack in React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm getting `unexpected token '?'` error. But, on debug mode, the error disappears.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was having this exact problem, but only in Android. The problem was caused by my use of a [nullish coalescing assignment operator (`??=`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_assignment). For example, something like:

```
obj ??= {};
```

React Native doesn't support this operator. Therefore, look for all occurrences of `??=` in your code and try changing it to the extended way; e.g.:

```
if(obj == undefined)
   obj = {};
```

You must avoid using this operator until React Native adds support for it.

(I'm not sure, but the [nullish coalescing operator (`??`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing) may lead to the same problem, so you may wish to avoid it, too.)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, this issue happened to me after I installed an example app with:

`"metro-config": "^0.72.1"` and `"react-native": "0.70.0-rc.4"`.

While my main app was still using `"react-native": "0.66.4"`

It also replicated when I reverted the code. So I came up with this solution:

1. Delete that example app
2. Reset
3. do the `yarn cache clean` and `npm cache clean -f`

And the problem disappears.